# Is there a video app which can position subtitles over black bars?

Tags: video, vlc, subtitle, mplayer

I've been happily using VLC for all video playback but now realised it's missing a feature I think is quite essential – having subtitles placed on the black bar below a movie instead of in the actual picture where it wastes screen real estate and annoys. VLC has a 'Force subtitle position' option which does not do anything useful with negative values. MPlayerX allows adjusting the position relative to the bottom, again, no use for negative values.

Can anyone suggest a player that can do this?

Comment: My guess would be 'no' - the player cannot put the subs outside it's own 'window'. I've been trying for years, with no luck, so I'm flagging this question in case someone has a solution.

Comment: The thing that confuses me so much is precisely that it _is_ inside it's own window. I don't think this is a technical difficulty.

Comment: Maybe ask on the vlc dev forums at forum.videolan.org

Answer (score 1):

I found this - [Subtitler Lite](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php?content=152364) VLC plugin,
which might possibly do what you need.

I haven't tested it myself yet, so feel free to add comments re success or otherwise.